# When execution reaches Me.Invoke, it hangs

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety, invoke, invokerequired

I have simplified my code to a single form, as follows:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class frmTest
    Inherits Form

    Public Sub WorkerSub(oAction As action)
        Dim x = 0
        oAction.Invoke()
        x += 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Test()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(Sub()
                          Test()
                      End Sub)
        Else
            MsgBox("Test")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnTrigger_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTrigger.Click
        Dim tt As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                                   WorkerSub(AddressOf Test)
                                               End Sub)
        tt.Wait()

        ' Never arrives here
        Stop
    End Sub

End Class
```

When `Me.Invoke(sub() ...` in Sub Test is executed, it hangs. No error is thrown & nothing written in the Event Viewer.

Even if I press F11, Debug Into, it hangs.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

JP

Comment: Show the content of `Test()`.

Comment: How is `Test()` being called? I'm not able to reproduce by calling `Test` from a background thread in an empty winform.

Comment: Invoke() can only complete when the UI thread of your program is idle, operating the dispatcher loop started by Application.Run().  Use Debug + Windows + Threads to find out what it is doing.  That should *never* anything like waiting for the worker thread to complete, that's a guaranteed deadlock.

Comment: Thanks guys.

I have simplified my code and wrote a simple form do demonstrate the error.

Sub Test simply displays a Message 'Test' on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Problem.

The main thread is waiting for another thread to finish.

```
t.Wait()
```

The invoke on the main thread needs to wait to, so there's a deadlock.